# Is it possible to declare a regulator in the device tree that can power down the system

Tags: linux-kernel, shutdown, reboot, device-tree

If I have, for example, a [fixed-regulator](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/regulator/fixed-regulator.txt) declared in my device tree, how can I request Linux to call the [disable](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.16/include/linux/regulator/driver.h#L166) function after shutting down?

Note, I use a custom regulator driver (not fixed-regulator) and I know that the fixed-regulator has a GPIO enable signal that could be rerouted to shut the system down. I'm looking for an answer that involves the regulator API.